# How to join multiple ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg

I am merging two .webm files using ffmpeg application(3.3.3) as follows,

1. ffmpeg -i input1.webm -c copy temp1.webm
2. ffmpeg -i input2.webm -c copy temp2.webm
3. ffmpeg -i temp1.webm -i temp2.webm -filter_complex [0:v]scale=640:360,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=640:360,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack;[0][1]amix" -vsync 0 -ac 2 -deadline realtime -cpu-used 8 output.webm

Above works fine for me but I want to do this in one step/ command. I am launching the `ffmpeg.exe` from my C++ application on windows so I have to do it for three times. I see that using `|` or `&&` doesn't work for me. If I try from command prompt then it works using `&&`.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why the temp files?

Comment: Some input files don't seem ok. If I use them ffmpeg stucks indefinitely  when it's about to complete. Creating temp file works always.

Comment: @user1939578 Can you provide the original input files so we can try to duplicate this issue?